# Python Merge list of multiple dictionary into one list based on a particular key using comprehensions

Tags: python

I have below 2 lists

```
entry1= [{'day': 'mon', 'temp': 5, 'wind': 10},{'day': 'tue', 'temp': 6, 'wind': 15}]

entry2= [{'day': 'mon', 'temp': 7, 'wind': 10},{'day': 'wed', 'temp': 8, 'wind': 25}]
```

Using comprehensions, how do I add the dicts using the key = day such that the output is

```
expectedoutput = [{'day': 'mon', 'temp': 12, 'wind': 20}, 
                   {'day': 'tue', 'temp': 6, 'wind': 15}, 
                   {'day': 'wed', 'temp': 8, 'wind': 25}]
```

Here, for 'mon' are the remaining two keys are added i.e temp = [5+7] and wind = [10+10]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is `***12***`? Why there are only `6` and `8` for `temp` but not `5` and `7`? Your expectation should be articulated.

Comment: @knh190  Corrected the editing error of **. For common key mon, temp and wind values are added.

Comment: And how do you suppose to handle the `day` value?

Comment: @knh190 If the value of the key = day is same, than the remaining 2 keys will have their values added, but if its different, than that dict remains unchanged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**2 Solutions** for this list 'entries':

```
entry1= [{'day': 'mon', 'temp': 5, 'wind': 10},{'day': 'tue', 'temp': 6, 'wind': 15}]
entry2= [{'day': 'mon', 'temp': 7, 'wind': 10},{'day': 'wed', 'temp': 8, 'wind': 25}]
entries = [entry1,entry2]
```

**A: one liner**

```
expected_result = [{'day':day,'temp': sum([i['temp']for i in [item for sublist in entries for item in sublist] if i['day']==day]),'wind': sum([i['wind']for i in [item for sublist in entries for item in sublist] if i['day']==day])} for day in ['mon','tue','wed']]
print(expected_result)
>>> [{'day': 'mon', 'temp': 12, 'wind': 20}, {'day': 'tue', 'temp': 6, 'wind': 15}, {'day': 'wed', 'temp': 8, 'wind': 25}]
```

**B: Basicly the same, but little bit expanded**

```
flatten = lambda l: [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
f = (flatten(entries)) # FLATTEN LIST


days = ['mon','tue','wed']
expected_result = [{'day':day,'temp': sum([i['temp'] for i in f if i['day']==day]),'wind': sum([i['wind'] for i in f if i['day']==day])} for day in days]
print(expected_result)



>>> [{'day': 'mon', 'temp': 12, 'wind': 20}, {'day': 'tue', 'temp': 6, 'wind': 15}, {'day': 'wed', 'temp': 8, 'wind': 25}]
```

I dont recommend **A** solution, becuase it is not efficient

Comment: `f` is the same as `entry1 + entry2`. It should be shorter.

Comment: And you're basically not supposed to know in advance `days = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed']`.

Comment: @knh190, both your comments are invalid. My answer is about handling solution, not some semi-step. And whether I know days or not, it doesnt matter to solution. days = unknown_list satisfies you?

Comment: I know your solution works but it iterates over the list N times, when each operation sums up `temp` and `wind`, it can be done within single iteration. You may argue that the lists are small here but a shorter / clearer explanation should be made.

Comment: I know but who cares? Its terrible solution but it satisfies the question. I dont like this attitude but what can you do if questioner demands it? There were 2 correct answers that got -1 because it didnt satisfy the demand. He wants list comprehensions so I give him list comprehension. Others gave him efficient loops and got -1. Dont bash me for answering the question exactly. If you can do my answer more effiecient, go on, but I guess you cant otherwise you would already did it

Comment: Sorry I've already answered it, and it's correct. I deleted it because I only posted the code and got a comment "it's not informative". :D

Answer (score -1):

This example, based on your answer dictionary names, uses list comprehension.I don't understand why you need list comprehension, but anyway, here you go:

```
def merge(dicts):
    my_dict = {}
    for i in dicts:
        day = i['day']
        if day in my_dict:
            my_dict[day][0] += i['temp']
            my_dict[day][1] += i['wind']
        else:
            my_dict[day] = [i['temp'], i['wind']]
    return [{'day': i, 'temp': my_dict[i][0], 'wind': my_dict[i][1]} for i in my_dict]
```

This is not related to your answer, just enter key('day' in your case) and list of dicts will be produced not matters how much values there are(last example is able to process 3 specific values, 'day', 'wind' and 'temp', now there are no limits):

```
def merge(dicts, key):
    my_dict, return_list = {}, []
    keys = list(sorted(dicts[0]))
    keys.remove(key)
    for dictionary in dicts:
        sorted_dict = {value:dictionary[value] for value in sorted(dictionary)}
        key_value = sorted_dict[key]
        if key_value in my_dict:
            count = 0
            for i3 in sorted_dict.keys():
                if i3!=key:
                    my_dict[key_value][count] += sorted_dict[i3]
                    count+=1
        else:
            my_dict[key_value] = list(sorted_dict.values())
            my_dict[key_value].remove(key_value)
    for dictionary in my_dict:
        new_dictionary = {key: dictionary}
        for i in range(len(keys)):
            new_dictionary[keys[i]] = my_dict[dictionary][i]
        return_list.append(new_dictionary)
    return return_list
```